# WordPress custom user_meta not saving

Tags: wordpress, meta

I have built a custom plugin and I need to be able to add custom meta to the user profile screen.

I have the meta showing but they don't seem to update. This is the first instance of this meta so it doesn't exist in the DB already.

The files are located in my plugin dir and not in my theme.

```
<?php

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_extra_social_links' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_extra_social_links' );

function add_extra_social_links( $user )
{
?>
    <h3>Web App Information</h3>

    <table class="form-table">

        <tr>
            <th><label for="companyname">Company Name</label></th>
            <td>
                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => array('operators','clients'),
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    ); 
                $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                echo '<select id="companyname"name="companyname">';
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr(get_the_author_meta( 'companyname', $user->ID )) . '">';
                foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>">
                      <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>  
                    </option>                      
                <?php endforeach; 
                echo '</select>';
                wp_reset_postdata();?> 
            </td>                         
        </tr>           

        <tr>
            <th><label for="companyadmin">Is this user a company admin.</label></th>
            <td>
                <?php
                echo '<select id="companyadmin" name="companyadmin">';
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr(get_the_author_meta( 'companyadmin', $user->ID )) . '">';
                echo '<option value="Y">Yes, is admin.</option>';
                echo '<option value="N">No, is not admin.</option>';                  
                echo '</select>';
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}


add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_social_links' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_social_links' );

function save_extra_social_links( $user_id )
{
 update_user_meta( $user_id,'companyname', $_POST['companyname'] );
 update_user_meta( $user_id,'companyadmin', $_POST['companyadmin'] );

}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

try use function get_current_user_id in $user_id

i think you use parameter but not send in hook